# javascript regexp surprise

Tags: javascript, regex, perl

I tried the following JavaScript in developer console of Chrome:

```
s = "mysessionId=PsGymRfxWIQG9gjNGgRlKw"
s.match("mysessionId=([^\s\;]+)")
```

A little surprised by the result:

```
["mysessionId=P", "P"]
```

I had expected that the () in regexp will match the entire "PsGymRfxWIQG9gjNGgRlKw", instead, it only matched the first character "P".

When I tried the regexp in perl, it does match the entire sessionId.

Any idea why?

Comment: The Problem is the escaping `"mysessionId=([^\s\;]+)" ==="mysessionId=([^s;]+)"`. So you would have to write it like: `new RegExp("mysessionId=([^\\s\\;]+)")`

Answer (score -1):

I should have used // instead of "".

```
s.match(/mysessionId=([^\s\;]+)/)
```

Had to laugh the moment when I figured it out.